# How can I intermittently show my history command number in my shell prompt?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

How can I intermittently show my history command number in my shell prompt? For instance, rather than showing it in EVERY prompt, just do it every 7 times. (I'm using zsh, but I think bash should be virtually identical.) The problem I encounter is that %h is not evaluated until it's in the PROMPT variable, and $HISTCMD is always evaluated as 0 for some reason. So putting a function like this into my prompt fails because $HISTCMD is always 0:

```
prompt_history() {
CYCLE=$(( $HISTCMD % 7 ))
if [[ "$CYCLE" = "0" ]]; then
echo -ne "$HISTCMD"
fi
}

PROMPT="$(prompt_history) blah-blah >:"
```

This can be partly fixed by echoing "%h" instead of "$HISTCMD", but only partly.

It is further complicated by the fact that the history command does not (seem to) function within a .zshrc file, so something like this won't work:

```
CYCLE="$(( $(history 1 | wc -l) % 7 ))"
```

(If you're using bash, change "history 1" to just "history".)

Also, the history file is not usable as a source of this information since (at least the way I have things configured--and I'd rather not change this configuration) history is not shared between sessions until a zsh session closes and its history is added to my $HISTFILE.  Therefore, this won't work:

```
CYCLE="$(( $(cat $HISTFILE | wc -l) % 7 ))"
```

I'm on the verge of believing this is currently impossible.  I'd love someone to prove me wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to delay evaluation of the prompt until it's issued. Just change the double quotes to single quotes:

```
PROMPT='$(prompt_history) blah-blah >:'
```

Comment: Maybe because you forgot to add `setopt promptsubst` (in zsh `$()` in prompt is expanded by default only in `ksh` and `sh` emulation modes, not in `zsh` mode)? And PROMPT works in zsh but not in bash: here you need `PS1` variable (which works in zsh too).

Comment: @ZyX: You may be right. However, the OP was primarily asking about zsh and, based on the clues in the question, I assumed that the appropriate settings were in place. If `setopt promptsubst` has been done, then the quotes are the issue that's causing the problem. Thanks for pointing out things that I should have been more thorough about.

Comment: d'oh!  That solution should have been more obvious to me.... Thanks Dennis for pointing it out!